# Can't log in after rendering login form in YII2

Tags: php, authentication, yii2, rendering

I wanna ask about my problem. Before it I wanna tell you what I do, I have `RenunganHarianController` and I made `actionIndex` like this. I wanna render the non-logged-in user to login form

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new LoginForm();
        //check user Guest or not
        if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->render('/site/login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    } 
    $searchModel = new RenunganHarianSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);        
    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

It's work, but when I try login from 'LoginForm' that rendered from that controller, I can't be logged in but if I try login from normal way, I can do that. Please help me, thank you

Comment: don't use  uppcase in your title in web is like shouting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that in your `site/login` view you have an `ActiveForm` with no specific action. If that is so, then the form's action is the same url that has been called, in your case `yourcontroller/index` (the `actionIndex` you have posted). The problem is that you have no logic in that action to handle te login process, which I guess is in your `SiteController`, `actionLogin`. You have two options here:

1. Redirect the user to `site/login` insted of rendering the view in your `actionIndex`
2. In your `site/login` view, specify the action for the form as `Url::to('/site/login')`

And yes, please, as suggested do not use capital letters as you did in the title.